# Using enums and reflection to call methods over a list of classes

Tags: java, class, reflection, enums

I downloaded a project to learn Java with, and I found an interesting way of modifying some big blocks of code.
I'm still new to Java and I don't know if what I did is more efficient or dangerous...
Syntax 1 is the before, and Syntax 2 is my method.

Syntax 1:

```
class Person{

    TestClass testClass;
    TestClass2 testClass2;
    //etc...

    public Person(){
        testClass = new TestClass();
        testClass2 = new TestClass2();
        //etc...
    }

    void init(){
        testClass.init();
        testClass2.init();
        //etc...
    }



}
```

versus

Syntax 2:

instead of doing:

```
person.testclass.doThing();
```

this method uses a hashmap and stores classes as the object and uses an enum as the key.

```
TestClass tc = (TestClass) person.attribute.get(EnumKey.TEST_CLASS);
tc.doThing();
```

.

```
class Person{

    public HashMap<EnumKey, Object> attribute;

    public Person(){
        Class2.sendTasks(this); //sends all classes
    }

    void init(){
        class2.initTasks(this); //inits all
    }



}
```

.

```
class Class2{

    void sendTasks(Person p)
        for (EnumKey ek : EnumKey.values(){
            try {
                p.attribute.put(ek, ek.handshakeClass.newInstance();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    void initTasks(Person p){
        for (EnumKey ek : EnumKey.values(){
            (TaskClass) tc = p.attribute.get(ek); //NOTE: all stored values (testclass1,2,3,etc) implement the interface TaskClass...
             tc.init();
        }
    }

}
```

.

```
enum EnumKey{

    TEST_CLASS(TestClass.class),

    TEST_CLASS2(TestClass2.class);


    Class<?> handshakeClass;
    EnumKey(Class<?> handshakeClass){
        this.handshakeClass = handshakeClass;

    }
}
```

Syntax 2 is so much easier, as I don't have to type out all the abstract methods of TaskClass each time I create a new class.
I can just create a new enum field and the rest is done for me.

But is this method good? Is it efficient? Is it slower? Or risky?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it efficient? is it slower?

You're using "reflection", so, yes, there is some overhead there.

Another possibility is to build the Hashmap immediately

```
HashMap<Integer, Object> attribute = new HashMap<>() {{
    put(0, new TestClass());
    put(1, new TestClass1()) ;
}};
```

> is this a good method?

That really depends on what you need to do, but it's the shortest way to iterate over a list of similar classes and dynamically update your other objects, yes.

You could extend that further with interfaces and abstract classes.

> risky?

Not that I know of.

There are other ways to do what you have without enums like iterating over all files in your classpath, but I'd say enums are safer

Comment: Is there any way to get around reflection? I tried to make it so the enum field's field (for a lack of terminology) is new TestClass(), instead of TestClass.class, then newInstance later, but that way every person's TestClass is the same... and not instanced..

Comment: If you need more than one instance, then you have to call `new` more than once. You can directly build the `attribute` Hashmap just as easily as you have the enums

Comment: Is there a default java method to do: new TestClass().newInstance(); instead of using TestClass.class.newInstance();, therefore reflection wont be needed

Comment: `new TestClass().newInstance()` doesn't really make sense

Comment: Yea i know, the handshakeClass field will be = new TestClass() instead of TestClass.class, therefore reflection is not needed, but this way only 1 instance will exist(the instance created when the enum is created)

Comment: You can pass a `Supplier` rather than a `Class`, e.g. `TestClass::new`. That will be much safer (since you know for certain that a no-arg ctor exists and is visible - or, at least, there's a method you can call that takes no args and returns you an instance), and avoids reflection.

Comment: Can you write up an example, I'm kind of confused, using: TEST_CLASS(TestClass::new) gives me casting errors

Comment: @Andy - You can clarify that in an answer